# CNTK Transfer Learning with LSTM: appending pretrained network to another network

Tags: cntk

I have a pretrained Seq-to-Seq slot tagger network as which in its simplest form is follows:

```
Network_1 = Sequential ([
    Embedding(emb_dim)
    Recurrence(LSTM(LSTM_dim))
    Dense(num_labels)
])
```

I would like to use the output of this as initial layers in another network. Basically I would like to concatenate the embeddings from the network_1 (pretrained) to an embedding layer in the network_2 as follows:

```
Network_2 = Sequential ([
    Concat_embeddings ( Embedding(emb_dim), Network_1_embed() )
    Recurrence(LSTM(LSTM_dim))
    (Label('encoded_h'), Label('encoded_c'))
])


def Network_1_embed():
    loaded_model = load_model(path_to_network_1_saved_model);
    cloned_model = loaded_model.clone(CloneMethod.freeze);
    return cloned_model

def Concat_embeddings(emb1, emb2):
    X=Placeholder();
    return splice(emb1(X), emb2(X))
```

This is giving me the following error 
**ValueError: Times: The 1 leading dimensions of the right operand with shape '[50360]' do not match the left operand's trailing dimensions with shape '[293]'**

For reference, we get [293] since emb_dim=256, and num_network_1_labels=37, while [50360] is the vocabulary size of the network_2 input. The Network_1 also had the same vocabulary mapping when being trained, so it can take the same input, and output a 37 dimensional vector for each token. 
How do I make this work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are using the entire `Network_1` as the embedding, instead of just its embedding layer.

One way would be to define `embed` separately and train it through `Network_1`:

```
embed = Embedding(emb_dim)
Network_1 = Sequential ([
    embed,
    Recurrence(LSTM(LSTM_dim)),
    Dense(num_labels)
])
```

Then train `Network_1`, but save `embed`:

```
embed.save(EMBED_PATH)
```

Explanation: Since `Network_1` just invokes `embed`, they share parameters, so that training `Network_1` will train `embed`'s parameters. Saving `embed` then gives you the embedding layer trained by `Network_1`. Quite straight-forward, actually.

Then, to train your second model (in a second script), load `embed` from disk and just use it:

```
Network_1_embed = load_model(EMBED_PATH)
Network_2 = Sequential ([
    ( Embedding(emb_dim), Network_1_embed() ),
    splice,
    Recurrence(LSTM(LSTM_dim)),
    (Label('encoded_h'), Label('encoded_c'))
])
```

Note the use of a function tuple as the first item passed to `Sequential()`. The tuple means to apply both functions to the same input, and generates two outputs, which are then the input to the subsequent function, `splice`.

To keep `embed` constant, clone it with Freeze option as you already did in your example.

(I am not in front of a computer with the latest CNTK and cannot test this, so it is possible that I made a mistake.)

Comment: I could just use the embedding layer, and it might be OK since when learnt end-to-end the Embedding layer would have learnt some discriminating vectors. However I specifically wanted to use the LSTM to extract the embedding as I the sequential process provides better vectors, for example if I had trained it to extract POS tags, and used the second network for some higher level LU task trained on a different dataset. I will try the tuple+splice combination with just the embed layer you suggested, but it would be really helpful to know how one would go about doing this.

Comment: There is one examples of Transfer Learning with Images (E.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Examples/Image/TransferLearning/TransferLearning.py) but I think its a bit simpler, as it does not have sequences and one can basically clone the last two layers like you have suggested. I was looking for something similar, but using sequences in this exercise.

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood. Can you try your code but replace `Concat_embeddings ( Embedding(emb_dim), Network_1_embed() )` with `( Embedding(emb_dim), Network_1_embed() ), splice`?

Comment: I tried what you suggested. Getting this error: [TypeError: CNTK Function expected 1 arguments, got 0] at Concat_embeddings ( Embedding(emb_dim), Network_1_embed() ).

Comment: Also for reference, I am actually trying to inject the first network inside the encoder part in the example given in [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Examples/SequenceToSequence/CMUDict/Python/Sequence2Sequence.py) , where the input is probably slightly tricky

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake, when i tried what you suggested, getting the same error: The 1 leading dimensions of the right operand with shape '[50360]' do not match the left operand's trailing dimensions with shape '[293]'